# Does having multiple `package` declarations slow the compiler down?

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt

I know that splitting a package declaration across multiple lines creates an implicit import. So this:

```
package com.me.project
package module
```

Is equal to:

```
package com.me.project.module
import com.me.project._
```

However, if an object in the `project` package changed, would it trigger `sbt` to recompile the current file, or would that depend on whether the changed object was actually invoked within the current scope? Basically, I'm wondering whether being more explicit, E.g:

```
package com.me.project.module
import com.me.project.UtilClass
import com.me.project.Rng
```

would help speed up compile times vs either of the first two approaches?

Comment: I very much doubt it would make a noticeable difference, but I think the only way to find out for sure is to actually benchmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it wouldn't help to speed up anything. Actually, it could mean that your compilation times even increase because doing single imports mean that the compiler have to parse more lines of code. But because that would still only take nanoseconds it doesn't really count.

An import declaration is nothing more than an information to the compiler about where to look up declarations. A compiler doesn't need to do anything with that information unless you reference it from within your code. In this case the compiler has to compile that file too, in order to being able to find out if your code would typecheck or not.

In other words, if you actually use two declarations from a set of hundreds, they are the only ones that would trigger a recompilation of your source code when they change.

I don't say that this is the only possible behavior, because it could be implemented in any way, but implementing a compiler in a way that it triggers a recompilation of your code when the code that corresponds to an import declaration changes doesn't make a lot of sense, when you think about it, that is why it is very sure to say that it will not do it. Because, what would happen? Every source files probably contains a package declaration and some imports. If your code gets recompiled because one of a declaration in the range of a wildcard imports changes, then this needs to happen for all other files as well. And because you can be sure that in every application all the existing imports span more or less the entire classpath, the entire classpath needs to be recompiled just because one file changed, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: Well, I think it's important to be clear on which part of the question you answer. Because using *specific* import (as suggest at the end of the question) make a *massive* difference in term of compilation time if there is implicit which would be put in scope with the global import... regarding multi-line package vs explicit `._` import, yeah indeed it should be the same.

Comment: Well yes, if an wildcard import actually imports more than what the user expects in what is being imported it makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah, just to be clear - I'm interested in the difference between "explicit and exact" imports vs "implicit and high-level" imports. I'll update the question